# Default value for Codable property that does not exists with PropertyWrapper

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i created a propertyWrapper like this:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
public struct DefaultTodayDate: Codable {
    public var wrappedValue: Date

    private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

        return formatter
    }()

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        var stringDate = ""
        do {
            stringDate = try container.decode(String.self)
            self.wrappedValue = self.dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate) ?? Date()
        } catch {
            self.wrappedValue = Date()
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try wrappedValue.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

and a model like this:

```swift
struct MyModel: Codable {
    @DefaultTodayDate var date: Date
}
```

so, if i want to parse this json file, everything is ok:

```swift
let json = #"{ "date": "2022-10-10T09:09:09" }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)

print(result) // result.date is: 2022-10-10 09:09:09 +0000
-----

let json = #"{ "date": "" }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)

print(result) // result.date is: Date()
-----

let json = #"{ "date": null }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)

print(result) // result.date is: Date()
```

but i want to also parse a json without `date` property.but i get. fatal error:

```swift
let json = #"{ "book": "test" }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)

// Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "date", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"date\", intValue: nil) (\"date\").", underlyingError: nil))

print(result) // i want to result.date be Date()
```

Comment: Due to how the `Codable` conformance is generated and how property wrappers work, this kind of "default value" is not possible to do with a property wrapper.

Comment: so how can we handle json and models like this?

Comment: I would just use `var date: Date?` and set it to `Date()` after decoding if it is null.

Comment: you cant do this if exists multiple date with different format in a json file

Comment: Oh you mean different properties have their own formats? In that case it might be worth desugaring your property wrapper and making it optional... Let me see if I can write an answer...

Comment: Why would this be better than using a custom `dateDecodingStrategy` for the decoder? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: if we have a json like this: #"{ "date": "2012-10-10", "newDate": "2020-11-11T10:10:10", "anotherDate": "22, May, 2022" }"#, i think we cant parse with `dateDecodingStrategy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a new `decode(_:forKey:)` method to `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol` (or `KeyedDecodingContainer`) that will automatically be used by default conformances of `Decodable`.

This method must take the `.Type` of your property wrapper as its first argument and return an instance of your property wrapper as well.

In your case, such an extension would look like this:

```swift
extension KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol { // KeyedDecodingContainer works too
    public func decode(_ type: DefaultTodayDate.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> DefaultTodayDate {
        return try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: key) ?? DefaultTodayDate(wrappedValue: Date())
    }
}
```

Then just add this initializer to your `DefaultTodayDate` type:

```swift
public init(wrappedValue: Date) {
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
}
```

Your example that was failing now works correctly:

```swift
let json = #"{ "book": "test" }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)
print(result.date) // 2022-09-08 08:16:33 +0000
print(Date())      // 2022-09-08 08:16:33 +0000
```

Comment: Oh wow that is very creative. I never knew the code generation for protocol conformances was before binding time. Relies a bit too much on the implementation detail in my opinion though...

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah it's a little weird, and kind of an undocumented thing. There are a lot of libraries that make use of this technique though, such as [BetterCodable](https://github.com/marksands/BetterCodable/blob/master/Sources/BetterCodable/DefaultCodable.swift#L51), [CodableWrappers](https://github.com/GottaGetSwifty/CodableWrappers/blob/master/Sources/CodableWrappers/Core/FallbackCoding.swift#L99), [DefaultCodable](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/DefaultCodable/blob/master/Sources/DefaultCodable/Default.swift#L30), etc. so it seems to be a fairly common technique.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md) for property wrappers, properties annotated with a property wrapper gets translated to a computed property and a stored property. The stored property stores the property wrapper's instance, and the computed property gets (or sets) the wrapped value.

For example, this is one of the variations:

```
@Lazy var foo = 17

// ... implemented as
private var _foo: Lazy = Lazy(wrappedValue: 17)
var foo: Int { 
    get { _foo.wrappedValue }
    set { _foo.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

Notice that in all the variations, **the stored property is always non-optional**. This means that when generating the `Codable` conformance, the property wrapper will always be generated as a `decode`, rather than `decodeIfPresent`, and will throw an error if the key is not present.

So `@DefaultTodayDate var date: Date` is not possible, but we can still use `DefaultTodayDate` as a normal type, assuming you want to go down the route of using wrappers to parse this.

First, add a parameterless initialiser to `DefaultTodayDate`:

```
public init() {
    wrappedValue = Date()
}
```

Then do:

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dateWrapper = "date"
    }
    
    private var dateWrapper: DefaultTodayDate?
    
    mutating func setDateToTodayIfNeeded() {
        dateWrapper = dateWrapper ?? .init() // Note that 
    }

    var date: Date {
        dateWrapper.wrappedValue
    }
}
```

You can avoid writing all the coding keys if you rename the `Date` property instead, and name the `DefaultTodayDate` to be `date`.

To decode, you just need to call `setDateToTodayIfNeeded` in addition:

```
var result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)
result.setDateToTodayIfNeeded() // if date key is missing, the date when this is called will be used
print(result.date)
```

You can avoid doing `setDateToTodayIfNeeded` if you don't mind using a `mutating get` on `date`, which I find quite "disgusting":

```
var date: Date {
    mutating get {
        let wrapper = dateWrapper ?? DefaultTodayDate()
        dateWrapper = wrapper
        return wrapper.wrappedValue
    }
}
```

```
var result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: json)
print(result.date) // if date key is missing, the date when you first get date will be used
```

Other options for parsing JSON with various date formats is [DateDecodingStrategy.custom](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy/custom), which is also worth exploring. You would just go through all the anticipated formats and try them out one by one.