# JSONEncoder encodes nil values when dealing with generic types

Tags: swift, encodable

Summary: `JSONEncoder` unexpectedly encodes nil values as null when working with generic types that wrap over a protocol.

Here's a short code that reproduces the problem:

```swift
protocol Event {
    associatedtype Contents: Encodable
    var name: String { get }
    var contents: Contents { get }
}

struct ClickEvent: Event, Encodable {
    let name: String = "click"
    let contents: Int? = nil
}

struct EventWrapper<T: Event>: Encodable {
    let name: String
    let data: T.Contents

    init(event: T) {
        name = event.name
        data = event.contents
    }
}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let event = ClickEvent()
let wrapper = EventWrapper(event: event)

let encodedEventData = try! encoder.encode(event)
print(String(data: encodedEventData, encoding: .utf8)!)
// prints: {"name":"click"}

let encodedWrapperData = try! encoder.encode(wrapper)
print(String(data: encodedWrapperData, encoding: .utf8)!)
// prints: {"name":"click","data":null}
```

The problem here is the fact that the encoder encodes the nil value instead of skipping it. And it looks this is caused by the associated type of the `Event` protocol.

How can I avoid this? Note that I cannot change the type hierarchy, as the actual code is part of a broader codebase. And the `null` value is rejected by the backend, so I really need to get rid of it.

The `JSONEncoder` class doesn't have any configuration options for nil values. Also, writing custom `encode(to:)` methods is not possible since generics are involved. Are there any other options to fix this problem? Re-architecting the app or changing the backend code are unfortunately not feasible options...

Comment: You cannot change the type hierarchy, but you *can* change the bodies of the types themselves, right?

Comment: @Sweeper there are many types conforming to the `Event` protocol, so any changes there would require a large amount of changes in the codebase, which I'd want to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually impossible to manually write custom `encode` methods in this case, since you just need to check if a "generic thing" is nil.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255038/5133585), you can write:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name, data
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    if case Optional<Any>.none = data as Any {
        return
    }
    try container.encode(data, forKey: .data)
}
```

Alternatively, [as I have learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73646007/5133585), if there are too many properties to encode, you can even write your own `KeyedEncodingContainer` extension:

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    public mutating func encode<T: Encodable>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key) throws {
        if case Optional<Any>.none = value as Any {} else {
            // even though value will not be nil at this point, we still use encodeIfPresent
            // because calling encode will cause infinite recursion
            try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

This "magically" works. The generated `encode` implementation in `EventWrapper` will resolve to this new implementation you wrote.